# Not Found (#404) Unable to resolve the request "gii/" in Yii2

Tags: yii

I am using the alpha version of Yii 2.I can acess the GII module via frontend but not via backend. The url '/advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=gii/' gives me 404 error. Any fix for the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out. I need to add this to the backend config file manually.

```
'modules' => [
'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
 ],
```

Comment: Why are you using Yii 2? As you probably know, This version of Yii is not for production

Comment: I knw..but i have enf time!

Comment: Oh, Sorry, Just intent to tell you that ;)

Comment: you should approve your own answer

Comment: You have saved my time. Thanks for the question and answer

Answer (score 0):

Today I got same error. I deployed my yii2 project on local OpenServer, but this server was loaded with option "HTTP" = Nginx 1.9. As soon as I reload server with setted option "HTTP" = Apache2 + Nginx, gii loaded properly. I hope it will help somebody.